# elastic beanstalk basic http auth for PHP / Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I wanted to implement basic http auth for my symfony elastic beanstalk PHP application. I allready found [this link where it is explained for an other php project](https://gist.github.com/pemcconnell/10394636) and tweaked it a little bit for my symfony needs.

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/allow_override.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      <Directory /var/www/html/www/ />
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
      </Directory>

  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/auth.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      <Directory /var/www/html/www/ />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Myproject Prototype"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
      </Directory>

  "/etc/httpd/.htpasswd":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      admin:lala
```

Problem is: I am not sure what directory to set there. 
I tried:

- /var/www/html/www/
- /var/www/html/www
- /var/www/html/
- /var/www/html

But none of this is working. All I get are some Error 503.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using Symfony, your directory will be: /var/www/html/web/

You also have to set the AllowOverride to All. Your File would look like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/allow_override.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      <Directory /var/www/html/web/>
        AllowOverride All
      </Directory>

  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/auth.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      <Directory /var/www/html/web/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Myproject Prototype"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
      </Directory>

  "/etc/httpd/.htpasswd":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      admin:$apr1$e2ahR98m$oQ9tE8rqr/l5XPr3cCZYK1
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your response :)

/www is allright, because of some reasons the folder is named like this. But the AllowOverride information is new. Thank you very much! 

In the meantime I solved my original problem through vpn-access :)